# st_gid e I-node com valores diferentes dentro da estrutura stat

Tags: c

Estou tentando construir um programa dentro da função `stat` que mostre o valor do `inode` e o valor do `gid`.

Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int stat(const char *path, struct stat *buf);
struct stat buf;
printf("st_gid : %d\n", buf.st_gid); 
printf("I-node number:            %ld\n", (long) buf.st_ino);
```

Só que o retorno é :

> st_gid : 12779520 I-node number:         -1076104514

O programa está retornando um número diferente de zero para o gid que deveria ser zero em virtude do arquivo ser de autoria do root e estar sendo executado como root e um número negativo para o inode. Quando após o comando ls -li  ele retorna zero para o gid e 263458 para o inode. Alguém poderia esclarecer onde esta o erro?

Answer (score 0):

Você redeclarou o método `stat`, e não atribuiu o valor em `buf`.

**main.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define PATH "/etc/passwd"

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    struct stat buf;
    //--------------------------------------
    stat(PATH, &buf);
    printf("%d - %ld\n", buf.st_gid, buf.st_ino);
    //--------------------------------------
    int fd = open(PATH, O_RDONLY);

    fstat(fd, &buf);
    printf("%d - %ld\n", buf.st_gid, buf.st_ino);
    close(fd);

    //--------------------------------------
    lstat(PATH, &buf);
    printf("%d - %ld\n", buf.st_gid, buf.st_ino);

    return 0;
}
```

**Saída:**

```
0 - 2378206
0 - 2378206
0 - 2378206
```

Os arquivos pertencentes ao usuário, tem o valor **10** no `buf.st_gid` (Referente aos meus testes).

Comment: Ok. Vou testar aqui pra vê se dá certo e retorno. Obrigado.

Comment: realmente está certo faltava atribuir valor em buf. Obrigado e pode dar por encerrado.

Comment: @uthacod, se a resposta resolveu seu problema, você pode clicar no **V** ao lado da resposta para marcar sua pergunta como respondida